# Super simple script using Popen via crontab execution failing

Tags: python, subprocess, cron

I have the weirdest problem that I cannot explain.  This script works fine when directly executed, but fails to work correctly when executed via crontab on one machine, but works fine on the crontab of another (same OS, RHEL 6):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def notify_helpdesk(result):
    ...

def main():
    proc = Popen("service auditd status", stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
    result = proc.stdout.readline()
    if "is running" not in result:
        notify_helpdesk(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Executed directly, ./audit_checker.py, performs the correct course of action every time.

Executed via crontab, "result" is always blank (not None, just blank), resulting in a call to notify_helpdesk.

And yes, the auditd service IS running.

Here's the crontab entry:

```
0 * * * * /local/sbin/audit_checker.py
```

This exact same script, on another machine with the exact same OS, using the exact same version of Python (2.6.6), and the exact same call via crontab, performs exactly as expected as a cronjob.

I tried this as an alternative and encountered the same issue:

```
proc = Popen("service auditd status", stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = proc.communicate()
if "is running" not in out:
    notify_helpdesk(out)
if err:
    notify_helpdesk(err)
```

Comment: Most probably it's a permissions issue.

Comment: Running as root on both, with root crontab: -rwxr--r--. 1 root root  942 Feb 27 21:27 audit_checker.py.  The script executes, it's the subprocess inside that is not working right (returning blank).  I know the script executes without permissions issues because the "notify_helpdesk" function properly sends e-mail to our helpdesk.

Comment: `pprint(os.environ)` on both machines and compare results. Set `stderr=PIPE` and call `out, err = proc.communicate()`. Redirect output of the script in crontab `>/var/log/audit_checker.log 2>&1`Unrelated: drop `shell=True`: `out = check_output(['service', 'auditd', 'status'], stderr=STDOUT)`

Comment: unrelated: if cron sends email with the command output on your system; you could run it using `cronic` that hides output unless there is an error: [`@hourly cronic /local/sbin/audit_checker.py`](http://habilis.net/cronic/)